# How to optimize MATLAB bitwise operations

Tags: performance, matlab, integer, bit-manipulation

I have written my own SHA1 implementation in MATLAB, and it gives correct hashes. However, it's very slow (a string a 1000 `a`'s takes 9.9 seconds on my Core i7-2760QM), and I think the slowness is a result of how MATLAB implements bitwise logical operations (`bitand`, `bitor`, `bitxor`, `bitcmp`) and bitwise shifts (`bitshift`, `bitrol`, `bitror`) of integers.

Especially I wonder the need to construct fixed-point numeric objects for `bitrol` and `bitror` using `fi` command, because anyway in Intel x86 assembly there's `rol` and `ror` both for registers and memory addresses of all sizes. However, `bitshift` is quite fast (it doesn't need any fixed-point numeric costructs, a regular `uint64` variable works fine), which makes the situation stranger: why in MATLAB `bitrol` and `bitror` need fixed-point numeric objects constructed with `fi`, whereas `bitshift` does not, when in assembly level it all comes down to `shl`, `shr`, `rol` and `ror`?

So, before writing this function in C/C++ as a .mex file, I'd be happy to know if there is any way to improve the performance of this function. I know there are some specific optimizations for SHA1, but that's not the issue, if the very basic implementation of bitwise rotations is so slow.

Testing a little bit with `tic` and `toc`, it's evident that what makes it slow are the loops in with `bitrol` and `fi`. There are two such loops:

```
%# Define some variables.
FFFFFFFF = uint64(hex2dec('FFFFFFFF'));

%# constants: K(1), K(2), K(3), K(4).
K(1) = uint64(hex2dec('5A827999'));
K(2) = uint64(hex2dec('6ED9EBA1'));
K(3) = uint64(hex2dec('8F1BBCDC'));
K(4) = uint64(hex2dec('CA62C1D6'));

W = uint64(zeros(1, 80));

... some other code here ...

%# First slow loop begins here.

for index = 17:80
    W(index) = uint64(bitrol(fi(bitxor(bitxor(bitxor(W(index-3), W(index-8)), W(index-14)), W(index-16)), 0, 32, 0), 1));
end

%# First slow loop ends here.

H = sha1_handle_block_struct.H;

A = H(1);
B = H(2);
C = H(3);
D = H(4);
E = H(5);

%# Second slow loop begins here.

for index = 1:80
    rotatedA = uint64(bitrol(fi(A, 0, 32, 0), 5));

    if (index <= 20)
        % alternative #1.
        xorPart = bitxor(D, (bitand(B, (bitxor(C, D)))));
        xorPart = bitand(xorPart, FFFFFFFF);
        temp = rotatedA + xorPart + E + W(index) + K(1);
    elseif ((index >= 21) && (index <= 40))
        % FIPS.
        xorPart = bitxor(bitxor(B, C), D);
        xorPart = bitand(xorPart, FFFFFFFF);
        temp = rotatedA + xorPart + E + W(index) + K(2);
    elseif ((index >= 41) && (index <= 60))
        % alternative #2.
        xorPart = bitor(bitand(B, C), bitand(D, bitxor(B, C)));
        xorPart = bitand(xorPart, FFFFFFFF);
        temp = rotatedA + xorPart + E + W(index) + K(3);
    elseif ((index >= 61) && (index <= 80))
        % FIPS.
        xorPart = bitxor(bitxor(B, C), D);
        xorPart = bitand(xorPart, FFFFFFFF);
        temp = rotatedA + xorPart + E + W(index) + K(4);
    else
        error('error in the code of sha1_handle_block.m!');
    end

temp = bitand(temp, FFFFFFFF);
E = D;
D = C;
C = uint64(bitrol(fi(B, 0, 32, 0), 30));
B = A;
A = temp;
end

%# Second slow loop ends here.
```

Measuring with `tic` and `toc`, the entire computation of SHA1 hash of message `abc` takes on my laptop around 0.63 seconds, of which around 0.23 seconds is passed in the first slow loop and around 0.38 seconds in the second slow loop. So is there some way to optimize those loops in MATLAB before writing a .mex file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's this [`DataHash`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272) from the MATLAB File Exchange that calculates SHA-1 hashes lightning fast.
I ran the following code:

```
x = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';  %# Just a short sentence
y = repmat('a', [1, 1e6]);                           %# A million a's
opt = struct('Method', 'SHA-1', 'Format', 'HEX', 'Input', 'bin');
tic, x_hashed = DataHash(uint8(x), opt), toc
tic, y_hashed = DataHash(uint8(y), opt), toc
```

and got the following results:

> `x_hashed = F6513640F3045E9768B239785625CAA6A2588842`
>   `Elapsed time is 0.029250 seconds.`
>
> `y_hashed = 34AA973CD4C4DAA4F61EEB2BDBAD27316534016F`
>   `Elapsed time is 0.020595 seconds.`

I verified the results with a [random online SHA-1 tool](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/), and the calculation was indeed correct. Also, the 10<sup>6</sup> a's  were hashed ~1.5 times faster than the first sentence.

So how does `DataHash` do it so fast??? Using the `java.security.MessageDigest` library, no less!
If you're interested with a fast MATLAB-friendly SHA-1 function, this is the way to go.

However, if this is just an exercise for implementing fast bit-level operations, then MATLAB doesn't really handle them efficiently, and in most cases you'll have to resort to MEX.

Comment: It seems to me that the options for speeding up SHA1 are using `java.security.MessageDigest` library or writing a MEX function. As I'm planning to make my MATLAB code compatible with GNU Octave also (and hoping to use GNU Octave as a development environment too), and as it seems that there are some differences in handling Java between MATLAB and Octave, using a Java library is a non-ideal solution. However, `DataHash` is really fast and for that reason it'll do the job before I'll implement a MEX solution or find an alternative way to implement SHA1 efficiently, without using Java.

Comment: Porting my own fMRI analysis toolbox to Octave is a long-term project for me, and I didn't want to limit answers based on that. Anyway, what I need at the moment is an efficient way to compute SHA1 for larger files (in MATLAB), to be able to continue with the development, and `DataHash` is a working solution for that.

Comment: @nrz: Octave has a compatible MEX API to write C extensions. They also have their own API for writing OCT files (equivalent to MEX files in MATLAB).

Comment: @nrz: forget that, there is already a [SHA1](http://octave.sourceforge.net/general/function/SHA1.html) function on Octave-Forge ([SVN repo](http://octave.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/octave/trunk/octave-forge/main/general/src/SHA1.cc?view=markup))

Comment: @Amro That's great! So the solution will be to check the environment, and use `DataHash` for MATLAB and `SHA1` for Octave. However, `SHA1` (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/packages
/general-1.3.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-api-v48+/SHA1.oct`) crashes Octave 3.6.2 on my computer, but probably the bug will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 3):

> why in MATLAB bitrol and bitror need fixed-point numeric objects constructed with fi, whereas bitshift does not

bitrol and bitror are not part of the set of bitwise logic functions that are applicable for uints. They are part of the fixed-point toolbox, which also contains variants of bitand, bitshift etc that apply to fixed-point inputs.

A bitrol could be expressed as two bitshifts, a bitand and a bitor if you want to try using only the uint-functions. That might be even slower though.

Comment: By replacing all my `bitrol(fi( ...` code with a my own rotate-left function SHA1 computing time for 1000 `a`'s dropped from 9.9 seconds to around 0.42 seconds, so now it's about 23.5 times faster than before. However, computing SHA1 hashes for longer messages (eg. the example message in FIPS documentation of one million (10^6) `a`'s still takes about 422 seconds (my original code took 9430 seconds to compute that), whereas running `time printf 'a%.0s' {1..1000000} | sha1sum` in bash only takes 0.953 seconds. So, 23.5x faster than my original, but still about 440 times slower than `sha1sum`.

Answer (score 3):

As most MATLAB functions, `bitand`, `bitor`, `bitxor` are vectorized. So you get a lot faster if you give these function vector input rather than calling them in a loop over each element

Example:

```
%# create two sets of 10k random numbers
num = 10000;
hex = '0123456789ABCDEF';
A = uint64(hex2dec( hex(randi(16, [num 16])) ));
B = uint64(hex2dec( hex(randi(16, [num 16])) ));

%# compare loop vs. vectorized call
tic
C1 = zeros(size(A), class(A));
for i=1:numel(A)
    C1(i) = bitxor(A(i),B(i));
end
toc

tic
C2 = bitxor(A,B);
toc

assert(isequal(C1,C2))
```

The timing was:

```
Elapsed time is 0.139034 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000960 seconds.
```

That's an order of magnitude faster!

The problem is, and as far as I can tell, the SHA-1 computation cannot be well vectorized. So you might not be able to take advantage of such vectorization.

As an experiment, I implemented a pure MATLAB-based funciton to compute such bit operations:

```
function num = my_bitops(op,A,B)
    %# operation to perform: not, and, or, xor
    if ischar(op)
        op = str2func(op);
    end

    %# integer class: uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64
    clss = class(A);
    depth = str2double(clss(5:end));

    %# bit exponents
    e = 2.^(depth-1:-1:0);

    %# convert to binary
    b1 = logical(dec2bin(A,depth)-'0');
    if nargin == 3
        b2 = logical(dec2bin(B,depth)-'0');
    end

    %# perform binary operation
    if nargin < 3
        num = op(b1);
    else
        num = op(b1,b2);
    end

    %# convert back to integer
    num = sum(bsxfun(@times, cast(num,clss), cast(e,clss)), 2, 'native');
end
```

Unfortunately, this was even worse in terms of performance:

```
tic, C1 = bitxor(A,B); toc
tic, C2 = my_bitops('xor',A,B); toc
assert(isequal(C1,C2))
```

The timing was:

```
Elapsed time is 0.000984 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.485692 seconds.
```

Conclusion: write a MEX function or search the File Exchange to see if someone already did :)

Comment: As far as I know, SHA1 can't be efficiently vectorized. Your `my_bitops` function seems an interesting way to try to speed up computing bitwise operations in MATLAB, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the performance issue. I think `DataHash` mentioned by EitanT will be the way to go before I'll write a MEX function or use a MEX written by someone else.